# How to add click event for many buttons JQuery?

Tags: jquery, delegates, click, bind, live

I have buttons that has ids like that:

```
id='button0'
id='button1'
id='button2'
id='button3'    
id='button4'
...
```

I want to add click event for all of them. How can I do it with most performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**simple**

you should use class instead !!!

```
<span  class="MySpan"> ...

<span  class="MySpan"> ...

<span  class="MySpan"> ...

$(".MySpan").click (....
```

Answer (score 2):

Starts with (^=)

Something like `$("button[id^='button']")`

Performance wise - not sure what the impact of ^= would be though.

ref: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("*[id^='button']").click(
        function() {
        }
     );
```